# How to get around using a function call in a select list

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Currently I have the following query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER (t1.value) > TO_NUMBER (MYFUNCTION (param1   => 'TEST'))
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END YES_NO
FROM TABLE1 t1
```

I am trying to optimize this solution for performance reasons as the same thing gets called in multiple places of the large query so I am trying to move all my function calls into the `WITH` clause.

```
WITH table_values
    AS
    (MYFUNCTION (param1   => 'TEST') test_val FROM dual
     )
```

How can I best utilize this value in my query above? Or is there a better way to avoid function calls in the SELECT list?

Comment: If your function doesn't depend on the database tables (or those tables change very rarely), then you may declare a function as `deterministic` (or `result_cache`) that reduces actual invocations.

Comment: Do you really mean avoid function calls in the select list altogether, or just minimise function executions, for example by caching the function result?

Comment: This particular function gets called a lot so I wanted to see if you I could minimize function executions

Answer (score 0):

(I know you use Oracle Apex, although you didn't explicitly mentioned it here nor tagged it)

---

I'm a little bit confused as you're saying "select list" (is it Apex' **Select List item**?), and then "multiple places of the large query". Which one is it? Hopefully, it is both - you have a large query which you then use many times throughout the application as a source of page's Select List item.

If that's so, then:

- `WITH` factoring clause seems OK to me (though, your 2nd code is wrong as it misses the `select` keyword)
- go to **Shared components** and create List of Values (using that *large query* & `WITH` factoring clause)
- on any page that used that query, don't set SQL Query as a source, but previously created LoV located in Shared Components

Comment: Select list I mean `select field1, field1, function(field3)` etc..

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function theboss RETURN varchar2
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'KING';
END;
/

WITH tb (ename) AS
(
  SELECT theboss FROM dual
)
SELECT e.* 
  FROM emp e
       CROSS JOIN tb t
 WHERE e.ename = t.ename;
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using joins as in reality my select has many tables and joins as is

Comment: It'll be a trade off. With the ```WITH``` clause it will be executed only once for the query but then you'll have a join. Other solutions are mentioned in the comments - ```RESULT CACHE``` will speed up things but the function call will be everywhere.